# WebStorm does not play well with gulp watch

Tags: webstorm

When I use WebStorm with gulp watch, watchify, tsc ... not all save commands trigger the watch.

I am sure that WebStorm has it for performance reasons but this drives me crazy.

Is there a flag which I can set, which saves the file immediately?

Comment: Maybe there aren't actually any changes when you hit save? I use gulp watch and the watch/reload will only trigger if there were actually some changes to the file (and not like you typed a line and then removed it).

Comment: I speak about the case where i change a line and save the file and watchify is not triggered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Webstorm support helped me with a quick response.

Turning 'Safe write' option ( Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings) off fixed the issue.